# IndexError with Basemap.contour() when using certain projections

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have run into problems when using `Basemap.contour` with certain projections. Based on the example given [in the Basemap documentation](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting_data.html#contour), I created the following working code which produces the expected result. The example uses the 'tmerc' projection.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


m2 = Basemap(projection='tmerc', 
              lat_0=0, lon_0=3,
              llcrnrlon=1.819757266426611, 
              llcrnrlat=41.583851612359275, 
              urcrnrlon=1.841589961763497, 
              urcrnrlat=41.598674173123)
##m2 = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0)

x = np.linspace(0, m2.urcrnrx, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, m2.urcrnry, 100)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = np.sin(xx/100)*np.cos(yy/100)

levels = np.linspace(-1,1,8)
m2.contour(xx, yy, data, levels)

plt.show()
```

However, if I switch to using the 'kav7' projection in the alternative `m2=Basemap` declaration (commented out in the example code), the code fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basemap_contour.py", line 20, in <module>
    m2.contour(xx, yy, data, levels)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 521, in with_transform
    return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 3542, in contour
    xx = x[x.shape[0]/2,:]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Note that this also happens when I define `lon` and `lat` values 'properly', the example was only chosen to be as short as possible. Does anybody know how to resolve this?

**EDIT**:

In case this is relevant, I'm using `python` version 3.5.3 on an `osx` Sierra machine. The `matplotlib` version is 2.0.0 and the `basemap` version is 1.0.7 .

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, running the code with `Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0)` produces [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vqHr.png) for me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see. Could this be an implementation problem? I'm on `osx` and all the relevant packages are installed with macports.

Comment: I have no idea. The error seems to come from within basemap. I have version 1.1.0.

Comment: I edited the question to give some version details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been [fixed 2 years ago](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/pull/308) and does not occur in any basemap version >=1.1.0, independent of the use of python 2 or 3.

Comment: I just checked, you are right. However, given the dates when I asked and answered the question, respectively, the problem was still valid about half a year ago. I'm guessing that, even though a bug is fixed in the code, it takes some time before the corrections find their way to all package managers...

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is according to  python3 integer division. Look for examples:

1) python3:

```
n=100
print (n/2, (n+1)/2)
```

Output: `50.0 50.5`

2) For python 2.7 this code returns `50 50`

Solutions:

1) manually update contour and contourf function of basemap with division for python3.

You have to write for integer `n`: `n//2` which is apply division from python2.

2) or run your program with python2.

Answer (score 1):

I found a really simple workaround to this problem. Instead of calling `Basemap.contour`, one can call `contour` directly on the `Axes` instance of the `Basemap`:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
m2 = Basemap(projection='kav7',lon_0=0, ax=ax)

x = np.linspace(0, m2.urcrnrx, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, m2.urcrnry, 100)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
lon,lat = m2(xx,yy, inverse = True)

data = np.sin(np.pi*lon/180)*np.cos(np.pi*lat/90)
m2.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)

levels = np.linspace(-1,1,8)
##m2.contour(xx, yy, data, levels)
ax.contour(xx,yy,data,levels)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following picture both under Python 2.7 and 3.6:

[image: result of the above code]