# IndexError when using some projections with basemap and contourf in Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap, map-projections, index-error

I'm using Python 3.6.1 64bits, Qt 5.6.2, PyQt5 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.4 with Basemap version 1.0.7, matplotlib 2.0.2.  When I try to use a **contourf** with **basemap**, with projection 'cyl', such as:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

map = Basemap(projection='cyl',lat_0=45,lon_0=-100,resolution='c')

nlats = 73; nlons = 145; delta = 2.*np.pi/(nlons-1)
lats = (0.5*np.pi-delta*np.indices((nlats,nlons))[0,:,:])
lons = (delta*np.indices((nlats,nlons))[1,:,:])
wave = 0.75*(np.sin(2.*lats)**8*np.cos(4.*lons))
mean = 0.5*np.cos(2.*lats)*((np.sin(2.*lats))**2 + 2.)

x, y = map(lons*180./np.pi, lats*180./np.pi)

cs = map.contour(x,y,wave+mean,15,linewidths=1.5)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 15, in 
>       cs = map.contour(x,y,wave+mean,15,linewidths=1.5)
>
> File
>   "/home/gab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py",
>   line 521, in with_transform
>       return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/gab/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py",
>   line 3542, in contour
>       xx = x[x.shape[0]/2,:]
>
> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

This error does not happen if I use for instance the projection 'ortho'. I have no problem running this code on Python 2.6. This question seems to be the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519804/indexerror-when-with-basemap-contour-when-using-certain-projections), which was not answered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to lanadaquenada  (I cannot coment it seems)

Based on Serenity's post you actually need to modify the basemap code, rather than your code. Basemap is old and not really supported anymore. It was created when python 2.x was released and it appears it utilised the python 2 integer division.
Python 3 now does division "correctly", but some old code was created to take advantage of python 2 division.

While using python3 and matplotlib 1.5.3 I would receive a warning about this issue, but it was not fatal. After upgrading to matplotlib 2.0.2 this error became fatal and my googling lead to your post.

Therefore following Serenity's advice you need to 
Manually change lines with

```
xx[x.shape[0]/2, :]
```

to

```
xx[x.shape[0]//2, :]
```

For me this was 3452 and 3644 in `path_where_your_python_libraries_are_installed/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py`

I am using basemap version 1.0.7.

I needed to make this change when transitioning from matplotlib 1.5.3 to version 2.0.2

This stopped my code from crashing and my basic testing against older matplotlib version appears to produce the correct results.

I hope this does not have unintended consequences else where, though basemap was designed with the old integer division so I assume it is OK

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :) This fixed my problem. In case this helps someone else, I use anaconda and the file was located at ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is the sequent of python3 integer division. 
Look for examples:

1) python3:

```
n=100
print (n/2, (n+1)/2)
```

Output: `50.0 50.5`

2) For python 2.7 this code returns `50 50`

Solutions:

1) manually update lines of basemap with division for python3.

You have to write for integer n: `n//2` which is apply division from python2.

2) or run your program with python2.

Comment: I don't understand how to apply solution 1. Could you explain further how to do it in my example? Thanks

Comment: Install python3.