# Python alternative to Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

Not seen any thread on this so thought I would ask, what packages are there available with similar functionality to basemap? I hear basemap is deprecated  (e.g. [IndexError when using some projections with basemap and contourf in Python 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852382/indexerror-when-using-some-projections-with-basemap-and-contourf-in-python-3-6-1)). It continually throws out warnings when using python3 and the version 2 basemap.

```
 /scratch/Anaconda_Local/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py:3608: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The ishold function was deprecated in version 2.0.
b = ax.ishold()
```

So my question is what alternative, well supported plotting library is out there for geographical plots?

Comment: Basemap is still maintained, but it is lagging behind the updates of matplotlib resulting in warnings all over the place. Mostly those warnings can simply be ignored. However, in the long run, Basemap is planned to be fully replaced by Cartopy. On the other hand some functionality of Basemap has not yet been built into Cartopy. You need to see if that matters for you. Note that asking question about recommendations are off-topic here.