# basemap.maskoceans: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib-basemap

I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

when I call `maskoceans`. Why is this? I'm running python3.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import maskoceans
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import interp
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

places = {
(-8.91508040128176, 52.23826465): 0,
(-6.45854802816101, 52.64127685): 21,
(-9.03867527891856, 52.78809005): 0,
(-8.70926037608263, 53.717247): 0,
(-6.8217677, 54.3303964): 0,
(-6.1658125, 53.5255827): 4
}

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-10.56, llcrnrlat=51.39, urcrnrlon=-5.34, urcrnrlat=55.43,
               lat_1=30., lat_2=60., lat_0=53.41, lon_0=-7.95, 
              resolution="i")

x, y, values = np.array([(x, y, v) for (x, y), v in places.items()]).T
coords = np.stack((x, y)).T

x, y = np.mgrid[-11:-4:10j, 51:56:10j]
z = griddata(coords, values, (x, y), method='nearest')

mdata = maskoceans(x, y, z, resolution = 'h', grid = 10, inlands=True)

plt.contour(x[:,0], x[0,:], mdata.T,linewidths=0.5,colors='k',z=99)
plt.contourf(x[:,0], y[0,:], mdata.T,cmap=plt.cm.Purples, z=100)
```

Here's the full stacktrack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 28, in <module>
    mdata = maskoceans(x, y, z, resolution = 'h', grid = 10, inlands=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 5107, in maskoceans
    _readlsmask(lakes=inlands,resolution=resolution,grid=grid)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 5132, in _readlsmask
    np.reshape(np.fromstring(lsmaskf.read(),dtype=np.uint8),(nlats,nlons))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 257, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 62, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 42, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Could you please show the full error trace?

Comment: @Thomas Kühn Added the error trace.

Comment: Ok, could you do a quick test: could you try to run this code with python 2?

Comment: Nevermind, I did the test myself. It works in Python 2, so you are running into a problem that is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44519804/2454357), only that for you the workaround I found won't work, because you depend on Basemap. On the other hand, I'm quite sure that I have just recently played with maskoceans somewhere -- I'll check.

Comment: @Thomas Kühn Thanks!

Comment: I found it, my own code also just works under Python 2. I'm guessing that you will have to either work with Python 2, or find a way to solve your problem differently. If you don't mind that coast pixels are shown 'half', have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626078/2454357), might this be good enough? There is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811775/2454357) to the same question, which uses `is_land()` pixel by pixel to mask the ocean pixels.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Thomas Kühn I used is_land(), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python3, you need to do a simple change to this file:

"your_python3_install_directory/lib/python3.x/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py"

Between line 5125 and 5130, find "nlats = nlons/2" and change it to "nlats = nlons//2".

This should solve the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem. Edward's solution solved it. Thanks Edward!