# IndexError while plotting netCDF data using Basemap, matplotlib and contour command

Tags: netcdf, matplotlib-basemap, index-error

I am trying to plot variables of pressure and wind velocities from the netcdf file of MERRA re-analysis data at a single level. I'm using the basemap module for the plotting and other necessary packages to get the data. Unfortunately, I end up with an error.

Here is my code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import os
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from osgeo import gdal 

os.chdir('F:\Atmospheric rivers\MERRA')
dirrec=str('F:\Atmospheric rivers\MERRA')

ncfile='MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Np.20180801.SUB.nc'
file=Dataset(ncfile,'r',format='NETCDF4')
lon=file.variables['lon'][:]
lat=file.variables['lat'][:]
time=file.variables['time'][:]

u=file.variables['U'][:]
v=file.variables['V'][:]
p=file.variables['PS'][:]
q=file.variables['QV'][:]

map = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlon=70.,llcrnrlat=8.,urcrnrlon=90.,urcrnrlat=20.,resolution='i')

map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawstates()
map.drawcountries()
#map.drawlsmask(land_color='Linen', ocean_color='#CCFFFF', resolution ='i') # can use HTML names or codes for colors
#map.drawcounties() 
parallels = np.arange(0,50,5.) # make latitude lines ever 5 degrees from 30N-50N
meridians = np.arange(-95,-70,5.) # make longitude lines every 5 degrees from 95W to 70W
map.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
map.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)
x,y= np.meshgrid(lon-180,lat) # for this dataset, longitude is 0 through 360, so you need to subtract 180 to properly display on map
#x,y = map(lons,lats)
clevs = np.arange(960,1040,4)
cs = map.contour(x,y,p[0,:,:]/100,clevs,colors='blue',linewidths=1.)


plt.show()
plt.savefig('Pressure.png')
```

Error

```
%run "F:/Atmospheric rivers/MERRA/aosc.py"
C:\Users\Pavilion\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py:3505: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The ishold function was deprecated in version 2.0.
  b = ax.ishold()
C:\Users\Pavilion\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py:3570: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: axes.hold is deprecated.
    See the API Changes document (http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html)
    for more details.
  ax.hold(b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
F:\Atmospheric rivers\MERRA\aosc.py in <module>()
     36 #x,y = map(lons,lats)
     37 clevs = np.arange(960,1040,4)
---> 38 cs = map.contour(x,y,p[0,:,:]/100,clevs,colors='blue',linewidths=1.)
     39 
     40 
C:\Users\Pavilion\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py in with_transform(self, x, y, data, *args, **kwargs)
    519             # convert lat/lon coords to map projection coords.
    520             x, y = self(x,y)
--> 521         return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
    522     return with_transform
    523 
C:\Users\Pavilion\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py in contour(self, x, y, data, *args, **kwargs)
   3540                 # only do this check for global projections.
   3541                 if self.projection in _cylproj + _pseudocyl:
-> 3542                     xx = x[x.shape[0]/2,:]
   3543                     condition = (xx >= self.xmin) & (xx <= self.xmax)
   3544                     xl = xx.compress(condition).tolist()
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

So, in summary the error turns out to be

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you using Python 3? In this case, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48624707/2454357) and the corresponding question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not using correct values for the x and y to make the plot. Basemap contour expects all x,y and z to be 2D arrays. In your case, x and y are most likely vectors of longitude and latitude values. In addtion, you should convert the longitude and latitude to the figure coordinates based on the map coordinates/projection.

Can you try:

```
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(lon-180.,lat);
x,y = map(lons,lats)
cs = map.contour(x,y,p[0,:,:]/100,clevs,colors='blue',linewidths=1.)
```

The second line should convert your longitude and latitude values for the correct x and y values for your selected projection.